# How to prevent an SQL query from discriminating between NULL and a '0000-00-00' value?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have some kind of query builder for the data filters in my application. Currently the code looks something like

```
if ($operator == 'null') {
    $sql .= 'WHERE column IS NULL';
}
```

But this snippet discriminates between a NULL value and an 0000-00-00 value. Is there a way to make the sql query consider 0000-00-00 to be equal null without adding

```
'AND column != '0000-00-00''
```

to the sql query?

Comment: 0000-00-00 is an invalid date and shouldn't even be allowed in the database.

Comment: No. Why should it treat two different values and datatypes the same? This does not make sense.

Comment: `0000-00-00` and `NULL` are completely different values. Therefore you would have to check for both.

Comment: You could make all `0000-00-00` invalid dates on your db as `NULL`, and then only check for null

Comment: I do not exactly have any power over the project. And it's impossible to change for multiple reasons. Oh well, guess I'll have to make my code a little bit uglier with the if statement.

Comment: Use a `NOT NULL` constraint with a `DEFAULT` value.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **NULLIF()** .
This will make the column a NULL if it's equal to 0000-00-00.

```
if ($operator == 'null') {
    $sql .= 'WHERE nullif(column,''0000-00-00'') IS NULL';
}
```

Comment: He is using `mysql` mentioned in tags